# Issue with desktop in Linux

Tags: .desktop, desktop-icons

I have two installed systems in Virtual Box : Mint 20.1 ; Ubuntu 20.04.2.0. And both didn't accept to freely(in any place) set icons on desktop.

How change it?

And who knows why in Linux not allowed to change icon locations on desktop by default?

Comment: What do you mean by changing icon _locations_?

Comment: Hmmm. I can move icons around my Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Levente, I mean, icons located strictly one after another. And i can't freely set icons where i want